# Symfony2 get path to xml file in src

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class in src/My/Bundle/Class and I need to use this function:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("path_to_xml.xml");
```

I have this xml file in src/My/Bundle/data/file.xml

¿How can I access to this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../src/My/Bundle/data/file.xml"`

Comment: And if I do this in a service. Have I to pass container: "@service_container" to do this?

Comment: yes, `@service_container`, but if you need the file, you can inject only the root dir : `%kernel.root_dir%`

Comment: thanks :) In service, to access would be $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() , right?

Comment: yes, `$this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir()`, but if you only need the root dir, you can inject it like this `%kernel.root_dir%` and access it with `$this->rootDir`